# IntentService stopping immediately

Tags: android, intentservice

I had my app setup where a (non-intent) Service would poll the location using a gps/network listener.  It worked fine since I was in charge of when the service would end (i.e. calling stopSelf() when a new location was found or the timeout was reached).  However, I recently read that an intentService may be more suitable for a long-running task as it is not run on the ui thread, but its own worker thread.  The problem is, now it does not allow the service to run for any time (I am assuming this is because nothing is actively happening in the service, while the listeners wait for a location to be received, and so the service ends itself).

my onStartCommand() method when it was a non intent service looked like:

```
@Override
protected void onStartCommand(Intent intent) {
    grabLocation();
}
```

Since I have switched the service to an intent service, I took away this method (as per the documentation, it should not be overridden for intentSerivce), and now my onHandleIntent service looks like so:

```
@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    grabLocation(); 
}
```

The service ends almost immediately.  What can I do to postpone when the service is ended?

I call the service like any other using startService(Intent)

```
locationPollingIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, LocationService.class);
updateLocationButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startService(locationPollingIntent);
        }
    });
```

Manifest snippet:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <service
        android:name="com.rperryng.intellilocation.backgroundServices.LocationService"
        android:label="Location Service" />

    <receiver android:name="com.rperryng.intellilocation.backgroundServices.AutoStart" />

    <activity
        android:name="com.rperryng.intellilocation.activities.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: How do you start your IntentService? How does your Manifest file look?

Comment: I have added the code you mentioned @EarlOfEgo .  If you were wondering if the service is started, it is, I have Logcat messages coming up from all over the service (including onCreate, onHandleIntent, grabLocation(), and onDestroy()) it just does not give any time for the listeners I have to retrieve a location update before terminating the service

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However, I recently read that an intentService may be more suitable for a long-running task as it is not run on the ui thread, but its own worker thread

Only for things that are "transactional" in nature: database I/O, Web service calls, downloading small files, etc. It is not suitable for cases like yours.

> I am assuming this is because nothing is actively happening in the service, while the listeners wait for a location to be received, and so the service ends itself

More specifically, once `onHandleIntent()` returns, if there are no more commands waiting to be processed, the service calls `stopSelf()`.

> What can I do to postpone when the service is ended?

Go back to your original approach, but have the locations delivered to you on a background thread, by using a `HandlerThread` and the flavors of `requestLocationUpdates()` that take a `Looper`. That way, when your location arrives, you are on a background thread and can do whatever you need to do with the location, then you can `stopSelf()` to go away.

However, this gets tricky, insofar as you also need a timeout, in case you never get a location fix. And, you have to worry about keeping the device awake, so it does not fall asleep while you are waiting for a fix. I wrote [a `LocationPoller` library](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-locpoll) that handles this stuff, though I have not used it in years, and so there is a fairly thick layer of dust on it.

You might consider using the `PendingIntent` flavors of `requestLocationUpdates()`, or its equivalent on the `LocationClient` API, as an alternative to any of this. Then, you can use an `IntentService` just for processing the *results* of a location fix.

Comment: Thanks for the very informative reply, I have looked at your library many times as of recent. I do not worry about losing the information from sleeping as location is not a huge component of the app, and I do not want to add the wakelock permission either.  

Do you feel using the handlerthread is still the best approach in which I just need to poll the location and save it into a sharedPreferences object?

Comment: Is this documentation what you refer to ? http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html#ExtendingService

Comment: @Raian1614: "Do you feel using the handlerthread is still the best approach in which I just need to poll the location and save it into a sharedPreferences object?" -- you should do disk I/O asynchronously. In the case of `SharedPreferences`, if your `android:minSdkVersion` is 9 or higher, you can use the `apply()` method on `SharedPreferences.Editor`, which handles the background thread for you. In that case, you could skip the `HandlerThread` and just receive the location on the main application thread, as you should not need too much time on that thread.

Comment: Thanks.  If I wanted to expand my project a bit to do some networking with the location would it make sense to put only the code that sends a network request in a handler thread?

Comment: @Raian1614: The only reason for the `Handler` thread would be to directly get control there in your `LocationListener`, as `requestLocationUpdates()` wants a `Looper` for background threads, and a `HandlerThread` is an easy way to satisfy that requirement. The alternative, if you have your `LocationListener` callbacks arrive on the main application thread, is to do your network I/O or other "heavy lifting" on a thread forked from the callback itself, in which case it can be a regular thread, or one from a `ThreadPoolExecutor`, or whatever.

Comment: Sorry I'm a little lost, I am not so well-versed in android threading. In reference to the second part of your reply, if I understand correctly, you are suggesting that in the callback methods for the `LocationListener` (such as `onLocationChanged(Location location)`), I should start a new thread  (regular ol' `Thread` type) and perform the network I/O on that thread instead? correct?

Comment: @Raian1614: That is one possibility, yes.